# How to get argument from constructor?

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

```
class AlmatyJobViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application){   

 fun clearSuggestionsHistory(){
            SearchRecentSuggestions(application, MySuggestionsProvider.AUTHORITY, MySuggestionsProvider.MODE)
                .clearHistory()
        }
}
```

> Unresolved Referense: application

How to get application from constructor, if i want to use it in this method?

Comment: add a "val" before application in constructor:  class AlmatyJobViewModel(val application: Application)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add `private val application` you will have exceptions in compilation time like

> Accidental override: The following declarations have the same JVM signature

So, to fix it, you only should to call `getApplication()` where you require.

```
SearchRecentSuggestions(getApplication(), MySuggestionsProvider.AUTHORITY, MySuggestionsProvider.MODE).clearHistory()
```

Comment: but why i cannot get arguments from constructor ?? it is possible in Java but why not in Kotlin?

Comment: This case was special because the kotlin compiler tried to create its own getter for the `private val application` variable for your `AlmatyJobViewModel` class but it was colliding with the same method name `public <T extends Application> T getApplication()` declared into the class `public class AndroidViewModel ...`

To test it, feel free to rename `application: Application` by `private val application2: Application` and you will be used directly where you prefer without `getApplication()` or even you can test it adding parameters to constructor as `private val` or `protected var` and so on